# What does Weak or Strong packaging mean in a SPA Javascript framework?

Tags: reactjs, angular, single-page-application, packaging

In one of the comparison charts between Angular 2 vs React , there was a mention that the 'Packaging' is Strong for React but, Medium for Angular 2. What exactly does this strength refer to ?

Ref: http://tutorials.pluralsight.com/front-end-javascript/angular-vs-react-a-side-by-side-comparison

Comment: that "comparison chart" is one guy's opinion;  the framework designers don't compare the 'strength' of their packaging....  If the context of that isn't explained in the article, it's probably best to ask the article author in a comment on that article.  Any answer you might get here would just be someone offering their opinion about what another guy's opinion means.

Comment: Sure, while i was about to ask the author, i wanted to see what is other experts opinion on this. Hence posted in the common forum.

Comment: this isn't a "common forum";  It's a QA site for answering questions involving *specific programming problems*.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the article was talking about this:

[image]

when u wanna use it,like this:

```
import {NgModule}           from '@angular/core';
import {HttpModule}           from '@angular/http';
import {FormsModule}           from '@angular/forms';
```